# why my array always stores the data just first index?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

```
while read -r line
  do
   local format=()
   for c in "$line"
     do
      format+=("$line")
     done
  for ((x=0; x< ${#format[@]} ;x++)) # this part just iterate 0 
                                     ##index because whole string 
                                      #stores only 0 index
    do
      echo "${format[$x]} $x "
    done
done <$1
```

This code just store the data in the 0 index for example i have a string that is "hello this is my world" this whole string is stored the 0 index but i want to store the each word in the string separately.How can i do that?

That is what i want ==[hello,this,is,my,world]

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 1):

`for c in "$line"` -- because you've quoted "$line" you are iterating over one single item.

To store the words of a string into an array, use `read -a` from a here-string.

```
read -ra format <<<"$line"
```

Comment: but if i write echo "$line" inside the for loop this will print separate doesn't it.@glenn jackman

Comment: `print separate doesn't it` - no, it will print single argument with spaces inside. This is visually/after printing indistinguishable. Try `printf "%s\n" "$line"` and compare with `printf "%s\n" $line`.